Magento 2.3.5 hacking problem
I'm experiencing a problem where, for some reason, an attacker manages to create user accounts in my administration, and manages to change emails for existing users.

I removed all malware from the site
redid the default magento installation
I changed the password for all users.
I installed a tool to check logs, and I noticed that the user simply appears in the administrative

I'm using magento version 2.3.5-p2.

please upgrade your magento 2 version

2.3.5-p2 has several known vulnerabilities, you should upgrade to 2.4.7 ASAP. Meanwhile, run a malware scanner to make sure there are no backdoors hidden on your system. Next time you find malware, make sure to note the 'c-time' (run stat <file>) which will likely correspond with a HTTP log entry.
See also this overview for secure/insecure Magento versions

Please also apply the below steps:

Enable Two factor authentication.
Enable recaptcha for login in admin as well as frontend form.

